# How to autowire crud repository in spring-servlet.xml?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We are getting the below error when are we using crud repository in spring mvc

> 4352 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
>   failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frCpbController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager
>   com.act.group.internal.controller.FrCpbController.frCpbManager; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'FrCpbManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager
>   com.act.group.internal.controller.FrCpbController.frCpbManager; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'FrCpbManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 22 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'FrCpbManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>         ... 24 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 35 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>         ... 37 more
>       Apr 06, 2017 12:55:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>       SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frCpbController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager
>   com.act.group.internal.controller.FrCpbController.frCpbManager; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'FrCpbManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager
>   com.act.group.internal.controller.FrCpbController.frCpbManager; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'FrCpbManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 22 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'FrCpbManager': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>         ... 24 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo
>   com.act.group.internal.service.FrCpbManager.itemA; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>         ... 35 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.act.group.internal.dao.FrCpbRepo] found
>   for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>         ... 37 more

Please help us in solving the above issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your question is not clear , but if you want to use CrudRepository in spring MVC project  :

1-create the interface :

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

2-scan the repository:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="*****" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
```

3-create the service and service Imp :

```
public interface UserService {

    public User findOne(Long id);
...
}
```

and use the repository in the service with annotation @Resource

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Resource
    UserDao userRepository;
@Override
    public User findOne(Long id) {

        User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
        return user;
    }
```

4-scan the service :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="*****" />
```

5-autowired the service and use it in the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
...
```