# JPA query need some guide

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have 3 Entity here A, B and C.

```
public class A extends B{
int id;
String name;
}

///////////////////////////////////////

public class B implements Serializable{
int id;
String name;
}

///////////////////////////////////////

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
@NamedQueries({ 
@NamedQuery(name="C.findByA",
    query="SELECT e FROM C AS e WHERE e.A = :id")
})
public class C implements Serializable {

int id;

@OneToOne
A a;

B b;
}
```

Entity A and entity B both have a relation with entity C.
in my case, I have a current id from entity A and I want to reach to entity B using a query from Entity C.

I've tried it in many ways but didn't help.
I tried this as my Repository

```
public QueryResult<C> findByA(Long id);
```

and then using

```
Repo.findByA(id);
```

also tried this one in my FacadeClass

```
C result=(C) em.createNamedQuery("findByA").setParameter("id",id).getSingleResult();
return result;
```

but it's not working.
i tried to make a query direct using Query() and TypedQuery()
none worked.

could anyone please help me with showing me the way or giving me an Idea.
it shouldn't be that hard, but i got some how really confused.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JpaRepository**

```
public interface CRepo extends JpaRepository<C, Long>{
C findByA(A a);
List<C> findByB(B b);
}
```

Comment: you can see more details here (i used crudRepository) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248495/how-to-autowire-crud-repository-in-spring-servlet-xml/43249794#43249794

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
query="SELECT e FROM C e WHERE e.a.id = :id"
```

[hql-query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Comment: nope, didn't helped. i also tried to change it and direct using JpaRepository, but still have the same problem